# Split allocated memory into two or more allocations

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, allocation

I want to read from disk a solid block of data which will then be split into many allocations that can independently be freed or reallocated. I could just allocate new memory at the proper size and copy the data over but I was wondering if there is a way to split the allocation since that seems like it would be a cheaper operation.

I would expect this functionality to be provided by the standard but I did not find anything like this. Is there a good reason why this is? And if not could it be implemented in some way?

Comment: First pick *one* language to work with. Solutions will likely be very different depending on which different language you pick.

Comment: The heaps in c and c++ both don't support this, you'll need to use some sort of custom allocator

Comment: What would be the general and important use case that makes this material for a standard?

Comment: I tagged this under c/c++ which is the languages I'm more interested about.

Comment: Please read the tags' descriptions!

Comment: ***if there is a way to split the allocation since that seems like it would be a cheaper operation.*** Why do you think multiple allocations would be cheaper than a single allocation?

Comment: Nope, this is not possible. Some memory allocators allocate different sized allocations in different sections of memory.

Comment: "cheaper" really depends on what aspect you're trying to optimize. From one perspective, it would be very cheap to just let the solid block of data remain as one solid block of data and only ever deallocate it when everything is done using it. No copying, no extra bookkeeping to manage a more sophisticated allocation scheme.

Comment: Well behaved code will respect the boundaries of the region of heap allocated. There's nothing preventing you writing well behaved code that deals with "regions within regions"... Why ask for library functions to do this for you? If you expect to delete and allocate "subsections", then write code that does that from the beginning...

Comment: At least for C (and I'm pretty sure also C++) there is no standard way to do a single allocation of a big memory trunk and then afterwards treat it as if it is a number of smaller independent allocations. If you really want something like that you'll have to implement your own memory manager on top of the standard memory manager. I doubt you can "beat" the standard implementations but give it a try. Good luck.

Comment: I think that just the fact that every dynamic memory block requires some metadata (it needs at least the size) makes this entirely unfeasible in general.

Comment: @kiner_shah it's cheaper to allocate one block and then use the same memory instead of allocating additional memory

Answer (score 3):

> I want to read from disk a solid block of data which will then be split into many allocations that can independently be freed or reallocated.

This requirement is flawed to begin with, because if we were to allocate a big chunk of contiguous memory and then manually free parts of it, the programmer would be taking liberties in acting as a manual heap memory manager. What to patch into the holes in the contiguous chunk and who will have the responsibility for doing that? It might just end up as useless holes in the memory map. You  may be able to do something similar with lower level, system-specific functions (`mmap` or similar), but standard C or C++ both strive to be generic and do not generally specify how/where things should be allocated in memory.

The proper way to do this is otherwise to use `realloc`. Then the underlying heap manager may free parts of the memory while keeping some of it in the same location, or it may allocate a new chunk and copy the data there, as it pleases. The caller of `realloc` need not worry their pretty head about it. In case of `t* tmp = realloc(original, n)`, the programmer should just not be assuming that `original` is still pointing at valid memory after the call. But rather do `if(tmp != NULL) { original = tmp; }`. And let `realloc` worry about if the actual data is stored at the same address or a new one.

Another option would be to not use heap allocation at all but to implement your own static memory pool of a fixed size. The main reasons for doing something like that is not to preserve memory but rather for deterministic allocations (embedded systems).

Answer (score 1):

It's not generally possible, so they didn't put it in the library. Some memory allocation algorithms could theoretically do this, but other ones can't. Some memory allocation algorithms only support certain sizes (and round up), or they put different-sized objects into different parts of memory.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can use `std::shared_ptr` whith empty deleter when you first "allocating" you structure and then use default deleter when re-allocating some objects. I.e. something like this:

```
#include <memory>

// This class should be standad-layout-class to be able to use placement new
class A {
    int a;
    char b[10];
};

class B
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<A> a;
    std::shared_ptr<A> b;
};

template<typename T>
void null_deleter(T *)
{
    // Do notyhing, memory managed elsewhere
}

extern char *read_memory();

int main()
{
    char *buf = read_memory();
    B v;
    v.a = std::shared_ptr<A>(new (buf) A, &null_deleter<A>);
    v.b = std::shared_ptr<A>(new (buf+50) A, &null_deleter<A>);
    // some code
    v.a = std::make_shared<A>(); // Delete old pointer and create new
}
```

But I hope you understand that memory allocated when you first read it from disk will not be affected by these allocations/deallocations and you can't use it as contiguous representation of current state, i.e. you can't write it back to file and expect that all modifications done to reallocated objects will be reflected there.

One downside of this approach is that memory portions which you do not use anymore will not be re-used until you free entire big block and so they will be wasted, but in some cases, i.e. when this happens rare or these blocks not very big this can be acceptable.